# How to abort a jquery function with the condition of an if statement inside it returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible for me to abort the rest of a function depending on the condition of an if statement that's inside it without using an else condition?

Code example below.

```
("#btn").click(function(){
    if(name == call_name){
     alert(err)
    }

    //abort the rest of the function below without the need for else
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: See the use of `return` in the answers.  Note that if the click would usually do something default by the browser, you should `return false;` to prevent the default action from happening (if desired).  Particularly important for anchors and submit buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a return statement to short-circuit a function.

```
("#btn").click(function(){
    if(name == call_name){
     alert(err)
     return false;
    }

    //abort the rest below without the need for else
});
```

Good point by others that in the case of an event like this you may want to return false to prevent the event bubbling and being caught by other handlers.  In the general case though, `return;` works fine to short-circuit the function and tends to be the clearest way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Return statement.**

```
 if(name == call_name){
   //do something
    return;
    }
```

Have a look [**here**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2323-Use-A-Return-Statement-When-Invoking-Callbacks-Especially-In-A-Guard-Statement.htm) (Your  case of Guard Statements).

Answer (score 2):

Just return false to stop the event from bubbling further

```
("#btn").click(function(){
    if(name == call_name){
     alert(err);
     return false;
    }
```